# Customize org babel execution command in C

Tags: org-babel, c, math

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
   printf("Square = %d", pow(4,2));
   return 0;
}
```

Now if I run this in the shell. I would first compile with: `gcc -lm file.c -o a.out` and then run with `./a.out`.

If I run the above code in org mode within `#+BEGIN_SRC C` and `#+END_SRC`, I would get an error "undefined reference to pow".

Reason is that the compiling command has no link `-lm`.  Is there a way to add this to org-babel execution of C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:flags` or `:libs` header to pass flags to the compiler (or libraries to the linker):

```
#+begin_src C :libs -lm
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
   printf("Square = %f", pow(4,2));
   return 0;
}

#+end_src
```

See the [Working with source code/Languages](https://orgmode.org/manual/Languages.html#Languages) section of the Org mode manual. That contains a [link](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html) to a page on Worg with links to details about specific headers for each of many languages: the specific page on C/C++/D can be found [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C.html).

Note that your program has a bug: `pow()` returns a double, so you need `%f` format, not `%d`.